# Axios PUT request to DRF Api going through, but not updating

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios

Hey so I'm trying to allow users to change parts of their profile after it's created, with a PUT request. In my network tab it shows code 200 and that the data was successfully sent.

I've checked inside my Api also, and it shows that that profile ID is the latest to have been added to the dataset. However, instead of the "test" value I'm trying to send to the field named 'bio', the default value still shows.

Relevant parts from my frontend and the bio field in Django:

```
      <div>
        <form method="put" @submit.prevent="updateData">
          <input type="text" name="bio" v-model="form.bio" />
          <button type="submit">Update</button>
        </form>
      </div>

    data: () => ({
      form: {
        bio: ""
     },
    results: null
  }),

    updateData() {
      this.$axios
        .put("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/actors/45/", {
          data: this.form
        })

        .then(response => {
          this.resultss = response.data;
        });
    }
```

```
 bio = models.TextField(default="3 Paragraphs")
```

Comment: Did you try checking what you have inside `this.form` before sending it to server? It might be a scope issue. Try adding `var scope = this` as first line inside `updateData()` and use `scope.$axios` and `scope.form`

Comment: @Gowthama Hmm, I'll give that a try. I can see in my network tab under "Request Payload" it says {data: test} so I assume it is being recorded. My code suddenly broke and I'm getting a 401 error atm, lemme fix that first and I'll let you know if scope works